# Save nested struct to gob

Tags: go, struct, slice, gob

I'm trying to save a struct to gob, but the file is missing the values of the nested type. I can save the Matrix type on its own, but the gob data of the Network struct doesn't include the Matrix values. Is there a way to save this nested struct to gob or do I have to split it?

```
type Matrix [][]float64
type Network struct {
     wih                Matrix
     who                Matrix
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must export the struct fields you want to encode:

```
type Network struct {
     Wih Matrix
     Who Matrix
}
```

Quoting from package doc of [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/):

> Structs, arrays and slices are also supported. Structs encode and decode **only exported fields**.

After exporting the fields it will work. See this example:

```
n := Network{
    Wih: Matrix{{1.1, 2.2}, {3.3, 4.4}},
    Who: Matrix{{5.5, 6.6}, {7.7, 8.8}},
}
fmt.Println(n)

buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := gob.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(n); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var n2 Network
if err := gob.NewDecoder(buf).Decode(&n2); err != nil {
    panic(n2)
}
fmt.Println(n2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zZc0MGban3y)):

```
{[[1.1 2.2] [3.3 4.4]] [[5.5 6.6] [7.7 8.8]]}
{[[1.1 2.2] [3.3 4.4]] [[5.5 6.6] [7.7 8.8]]}
```